# How to copy 3x entire rows only when a cell value change in a specific column (Solved)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an issue I can't solve with the existing Stackoverflow questions.
I am trying to achieve the following:

Within active worksheet (if module, then with worksheet("data"))
In the column "I", if an entry value is made = "Y" it needs to trigger the following.

- Copy paste the row (range column A:H) where "Y" conditions was entered, add it 3 times and place is above the initial row. The copy paste should exclude and let column "I" empty for the new rows.
- then in the new inserted cell (column A only), change the date of the original cell by a formulas: *row 1 Ax cell = Initial day - 07 calendar days (excluding weekend)
  *row 2 Ax cell = initial day - 14 calendar days (excluding weekend)
  *row 3 Ax cell = initial day - 21 calendar days (excluding weekend)
- then trigger a message box: "Do you want to proceed with Outlook invite", triggering a "Y" (macro continue to open Outlook calendar invite" or "N" (end the macro).

At the stage of the macro below, I got object error so I cannot proceed with the Outlook steps.
Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim Col As Variant
Dim BlankRows As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim StartRow As Long

Col = "I"
StartRow = 1
BlankRows = 1
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet
    For R = LastRow To StartRow + 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(R, Col) = "Y" Then
            .Cells(R, Col).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next R
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worksheet_change() event has a parameter, called `target`. It is defined as a Range and represents the Range that triggered the event (meaning the Range that has changed).

By using this parameter you can easily distinguish between the Rows/Cells that have changed and the ones that stayed the same.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Const columnID As Long = 9
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim newRow As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo TearDown

For Each targetCell In target 'changed Range can be more than 1 Cell so this loops through that collection
    With targetCell
        If .Column <> columnID Then Exit For
        If .Value = "Y" Then
            With .EntireRow
                .Insert Shift:=xlUp
                .Copy
                Set newRow = .Offset(-1)
                newRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End With
            newRow.Cells(1, columnID).Clear
        End If
    End With
Next targetCell
TearDown:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This Sub will now create a newLine above the line that changed it's value in Column "I" to "Y" and copy the values into the new Line (and clear Column I)

The number Of times a newCell is inserted, or the function to change the Date in column A or the message box are all things you should be able to implement from here.

*The `Application.EnableEvents = False` is required (and if not highly advised) since you could otherwise run into an infinite loop, since the sub changes the sheet and is called when the sheet get's changed.

Edit: to insert more than 1 row (or basically doing the same thing 3 times) you can extract the logic that creates the new row and does all the changing into a sub/function, and call that 3 times

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim newRow As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo TearDown

For Each targetCell In target 'changed Range can be more than 1 Cell so this loops through that collection
    With targetCell
        If .Column <> columnID Then Exit For
        If .Value = "Y" Then
            Set newRow = getDuplicatedRow(targetCell.EntireRow)
            Set newRow = getDuplicatedRow(newRow)
            Set newRow = getDuplicatedRow(newRow)
        End If
    End With
Next targetCell
TearDown:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Function getDuplicatedRow(targetRow As Range) As Range
    Dim newRow As Range
    
    With targetRow
        .Insert Shift:=xlUp
        .Copy
        Set newRow = .Offset(-1)
        newRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    newRow.Cells(1, columnID).Clear
    newRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = newRow.Cells(1, 2).Value + 1
    Set getDuplicatedRow = newRow
End Function
```

and Module1:

```
Option Explicit

Global Const columnID As Long = 9
'you can only declare Global consts in regular modules, so that's why this is here
'how/where you handle your columnID is up to you, just change it to fit your needs
```

This will create 3 new Rows ... each row being based on the row before it. So the first row you insert will be copied and changed from the row that changed. The 2nd row will get copied and changed from the 1st row and the 3rd row from the 2nd. (I have illustrated this in my code by having the 2nd column add 1 to the column it is copied from)

Comment: Thank you so much @Lord-JulianLXII, how about if I need to insert 3 rows instead of 1 with the same conditions?

Comment: @Guillaume see my edit - I made it so that for multiple insertions/copies it is the new row you created that get's copied (this way you can very easily implement incremental changes (like the one in your post with the dates)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, couldn't find the proper solutions, and spent 3hrs turning around. I think I can work it out for the rest of the code now.